# Show Facebook Timeline on my app

Tags: android, facebook

Hello everybody i'd just like to know if it's possible to show a user timeline on my app.
i want an anctivity to show just a specific timeline.
I tried with a webview linked to the timeline but i can see obviously also all of the other facebbok features like news, search, notifications ecc.
I'd like to show just a specific timeline,not anything else.
It's that possible?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this is not possible. Using the Graph API and [/me/home](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/home) , you can get the posts of the newsfeed for a specific user (if that posts allows the display in third party apps) but you will have to display it yourself.

Comment: But i also saw that its possibile to hide some part of a website in a web view. I mean this is probably possible to do with simple websites,but do you think it would work with Facebook? Or is it science fiction?

Comment: That could possibly work somehow (using JS or a custom CSS to hide a lot of content on the main page) but this has two problems: a) you're misusing Facebook and maybe even working against their TOS (which is bad, legally) and b) you're very prone to your app breaking when they change their side. Which they do often.

Comment: i guess the same, do you think i could do it using graph API? Cause i saw the documentation but i am not sure i can remake the same timeline effects. Anyway thank you for your answers, i ll try to handle it somehow.

Comment: To do it via API you would need `read_stream` permission from the user, and that you will not get granted in review for an android app.